# Adding numbers in a sequence

Tags: sequence

I have a basic problem. 
If we are to input:

```
6
1 2 3 4 10 11
```

The desired outcome should be:

```
31
```

Here is the coding, you must simply finish the function and it should work:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys

def simpleArraySum(n, ar):
    # Complete this function

n = int(input().strip())
ar = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
result = simpleArraySum(n, ar)
print(result)
```

We want 1+2+3+4+10+11 = 31

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum()`.

```
def simpleArraySum(n, ar):
    return sum(ar[:n])
```

The `[:n]` truncates the array to n elements.